# Save echo as output within script

Tags: bash, echo, fastq

The following is a little bit of my code:

```
for((a=1;a<=8000000;a++))
do
  if (($a%4==0))
  then  
      b=`cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$a|tail -1|sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'|wc -c`
      echo `cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$(($a-3))|tail -1`
      echo `cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$(($a-2))|tail -1|cut -c 1-$(($b-1))`
      echo `cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$(($a-1))|tail -1`
      echo `cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$a|tail -1|sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'`
  fi
done
```

This if loop is "echo" the output; however I hope to save the echo output into some file. And I wanna manage this WITHIN script.
I mean probably sth. like:

```
`for((a=1;a<=8000000;a++))
do
  if (($a%4==0))
  then  
      b=`cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$a|tail -1|sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'|wc -c`
      echo `cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$(($a-3))|tail -1`
      echo `cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$(($a-2))|tail -1|cut -c 1-$(($b-1))`
      echo `cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$(($a-1))|tail -1`
      echo `cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$a|tail -1|sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'`
  fi
done` > output
```

But obviously this doesn't work; and I'm asking for the right way to save echo output within script.

thx

Answer (score 3):

Always a good practice to use $(…) instead of ``.

```
for((a=1;a<=8000000;a++))
do
  if (($a%4==0))
  then  
      b=$(cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$a|tail -1|sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'|wc -c)
      echo $(cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$(($a-3))|tail -1)
      echo $(cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$(($a-2))|tail -1|cut -c 1-$(($b-1)))
      echo $(cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$(($a-1))|tail -1)
      echo $(cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$a|tail -1|sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g')
  fi
done >> output
```

**Update:**

As **@Sorpigal** suggested, this still uses `cat` command when we can do the same with `head`

Comment: Good advice, but this is still a Useless Use Of Cat. `head` could be passed the file name directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can append `>> output` to each of the echo lines.

Also the `echo` is redundant in your script. Instead of

```
echo `cat ...`
```

you can use

```
cat ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove backticks and keep redirect.

Alternatively you can

```
exec >output
```

before the `for`.